# Erratic sort order for hybrid_property sum expression in Flask-Admin using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given the following models, I would like to add a sortable column to Flask Admin that shows all upcoming payments for an `Organisation`:

```
organisation_payments = db.Table(
    'organisation_payments',
    db.Column('payment_id', MyUUID(), db.ForeignKey('payment.id')),
    db.Column('organisation_id', MyUUID(), db.ForeignKey('organisation.id'))
)

class Organisation(db.Model):
    id = Column(ModelUUID(), primary_key=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def upcoming_payments(self):
        payments = Payment.query.filter(
            Payment.organisations.any(id=self.id),
            Payment.status == 'active'
        ).all()

        return sum([payment.amount for payment in payments])

    @upcoming_payments.expression
    def upcoming_payments(cls):
        return select([
            func.sum(Payment.amount)
        ]).where(and_(
            organisation_payments.c.organisation_id == cls.id,
            Payment.status == 'active'
        )).label('upcoming_payments')

class Payment(db.Model):
    id = Column(ModelUUID(), primary_key=True)
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer())
    status = db.Column(db.Unicode(255), default='active')
    organisations = db.relationship(
        'Organisation',
        secondary=organisation_payments,
        backref=db.backref('payments', lazy='dynamic')
    )
```

Note that a `Payment` could theoretically be mapped to multiple `Organisation`s, hence the many-to-many relationship.

I have added `upcoming_payments` to `column_sortable_list` in a Flask-Admin `ModelView`, but when sorting on that column the results are erratic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxrAE.png

This is the most minimal version of the code, but I've also tried:

1. using `coalesce` to force `0` for rows with no upcoming payments
2. using `as_scalar()` in place of `.label()`
3. `Payment.organisations.any(id=cls.id)` in place of `organisation_payments.c.organisation_id == cls.id` (this produced even more confusing and inconsistent results, and sorting `asc`/`desc` made no difference)

The values returned from the regular `hybrid_property` *are* correct, as is the result if I run this in the shell:

```
stmt = select([
        func.sum(Payment.amount)
    ]).where(and_(
        Payment.organisations.any(id=org.id),
        Payment.status == 'active',
    ))

res = db.engine.execute(stmt)
res.fetchone() 
(4036200L,)
```

However the result is wildly inaccurate if I run this:

```
stmt = select([
        func.sum(Payment.amount)
    ]).where(and_(
        organisation_payments.c.organisation_id == org.id,
        Payment.status == 'active',
    ))

res = db.engine.execute(stmt)
res.fetchone() 
(1204440000L,)
```

But neither the `any()` or association table method returns the correct sort order in Flask-Admin. What am I doing wrong here? I feel like I must be missing a `distinct` or a subquery, but I'm stumped.

UPDATE: All thanks to Ilja Everilä for guiding me to the answer:

```
    @upcoming_payments.expression
    def upcoming_payments(cls):
        q = select([coalesce(func.sum(Payment.amount), 0)])
        q = q.where(and_(
            organisation_payments.c.charity_id == cls.id,
            Payment.status == 'active',
            Payment.deleted.isnot(True)
        ))

        j = Payment.__table__.join(organisation_payments)
        q = q.select_from(j)

        return q.label('upcoming_donations')
```

Comment: It looks like there's a join missing between Payment and organisation_payments in the hybrid expression's query, which results in a cross join between them.

Comment: @IljaEverilä That was it, thank you! I'll edit the post with the correct answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can (should) also post the actual solution as an answer, instead of just editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: All thanks to Ilja Everilä for guiding me to the answer:

```
    @upcoming_payments.expression
    def upcoming_payments(cls):
        q = select([coalesce(func.sum(Payment.amount), 0)])
        q = q.where(and_(
            organisation_payments.c.charity_id == cls.id,
            Payment.status == 'active',
            Payment.deleted.isnot(True)
        ))

        j = Payment.__table__.join(organisation_payments)
        q = q.select_from(j)

        return q.label('upcoming_donations')
```